# Not getting string from bin file

Tags: c++, string, fstream

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int numcount; //amount of numbers
int numb; //temporary number for writing reaction
fstream fbin ("filename.bin", ios::binary | ios::out);
if (!fbin){
    cout << "err";
    return -1;

}
char thing[6]; //reading of Done!
cout << "Starting Write Sequence...\n";
cout << "How many numbers do you want to write?\n";
cin >> numcount;
cout << "Okay, " << numcount << " numbers.\n";
fbin.write((char*)(&numcount), 4); //writes amount of numbers to first
for(int i = 0; i < numcount; i++){ //loop that writes numcount numbers to file
    cout << "Enter number " << i + 1 << ": ";
    cin >> numb;
    cout << "Number " << numb << " entered. Writing...\n";
    fbin.write((char*)(&numb), 4);
}
fbin.write("Done!", sizeof("Done!") - 1);
fbin.seekp(numcount * 4 + 4); //Finds position of Done!. numcount * 4 because normal integers are 4 bytes,
//and + 4 because I also need to include numcount in the file, so it can be read.
fbin.read(thing, 5);
cout << thing << "\n";
cout << "\"Done!\" should have appeared before this!";
}
```

The last part of this code is supposed to print

```
Done!
```

to the console, but instead it prints @.

Here is what the binary file has with 4 numbers (7, 5, 8, 7):

```
04 00 00 00 07 00 00 00 05 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 07 00 00 00 44 6F 6E 65 21

....................Done!
```

Edit: accidentally removed fbin.read(thing, 5); still does the same thing

Comment: Where did you ever read anything into the `thing` buffer in your code??

Comment: Looks like a typo.  `fbin.seekp` should be `fbin.seekg` as you want to advance the **g**et pointer not the **p**ut pointer

Comment: @NathanOliver Still does the same thing (@ sign)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit How would I fix this?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'm trying to read `Done!` from filename.bin to the console, as the string `thing`

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yes, I replied to it, and now it is in my code, but it is still the same, with an @ instead of Done!

Answer (score 0):

You're opening the stream in "output" mode, and you're seeking with `seekp` rather than `seekg`. This ruins your ability to read from the file, and to do so at the correct place. Performing some error checking on the result of your operations would have revealed this!

Since you want to use binary mode you can't omit the stream flags entirely, so I propose:

```
fstream fbin("filename.bin", ios::binary | ios::in | ios::out);
//                                      ^^^^^^^^^^
```

And, later:

```
fbin.seekg(numcount * 4 + 4);
//       ^
```

Furthermore, you should not assume that integers are four bytes wide. All these magic number `4`s should be replaced with `sizeof(int)`.

Comment: Thanks, I needed the ios::in